# Nested media queries output

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I've recently switched from SASS to Less (work) and was wondering if it would be possible to get this output from Less (using a mixin):

```
footer {
  width: 768px;
   @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    width:900px;
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
     width:1200px;
   }
}
```

I can only seem to get the output in separate breakpoints like so (instead of under the selector):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px) {
 footer {
  width: 768px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 footer {
   width: 3939px;
 }
}
```

this is the mixin I've been using:

```
.respond-to(@respondto; @rules) when (@respondto = "lg") {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    @rules();
  }
}
.respond-to(@respondto; @rules) when (isnumber(@respondto)) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: @respondto) {
   @rules();
  }
}
```

And then using it like so:

```
div.class {
   .respond-to(120px, {
     float:left;
   });
   .respond-to("lg", {
     float:none;
   });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The output of your mixin (when it is compiled) would be a CSS code and I am afraid the first sample (where media queries is nested within the element) is not valid CSS.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer because "No" is a valid answer for the question and I get a bit more space to show how your mixin can be made more DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

No, you cannot get the output you require by using Less mixins (unless you end up doing some really ugly hacks).

**Long Answer:**

Less, SASS etc are (as you would already know) CSS pre-processors. Their main usage is to enable writing of DRY code and quicker creation of CSS (there are other perks, but these are the primary reasons to use them). The pre-processor would hence be of no use if it produces an output that is not a valid CSS code - because ultimately it is the CSS that actually gets used in your projects.

The below snippet is not valid CSS because such a structure is not supported and so Less would never produce an output like that.

<sup>Note: This however is a valid Less code structure because Less supports nesting of selectors and media queries.</sup>

```
footer {
  width: 768px;
   @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    width:900px;
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
     width:1200px;
   }
}
```

Below is a snippet to show what I had meant by *not valid CSS*. Check how the media queries affect the `color` but not the `background`.

```css
/* Invalid CSS */
footer {
  background: beige;
   @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    background: blue;
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
     background: green;
   }
}

/* Valid CSS */

footer {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  footer{
    color: blue;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  footer{
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>This is a footer</footer>
```

---

Coming to your mixin, you could re-write it like in the below snippet

```
.respond-to(@respondto; @rules){
     & when (@respondto = "lg") {
      @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        @rules();
      }
    }
    & when (isnumber(@respondto)) {
      @media only screen and (min-width: @respondto) {
       @rules();
      }
    }
}
```

or like the one below to keep your code DRY.

```
.respond-to(@respondto; @rules){
  .set-width(@respondto); // call to set the media query width depending on input
  @media only screen and (min-width: @width) {
    @rules();
  }
}
.set-width(@respondto) when (@respondto = "lg") {
  @width: 1200px;
}
.set-width(@respondto) when (isnumber(@respondto)) {
  @width: @respondto;
}
```